# Сокеты в python: параметр backlog у socket.listen() метода

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Здравствуйте. Написал простое клиент-серверное приложение используя сокеты. Клиент отправляет строку серверу, сервер переводит эту строку в верхний регистр и отправляет клиенту, а клиент просто печатает эту строку.

```
#Сервер
import socket
from threading import Thread

def handler(client_socket, cli_address):
    print(client_address, 'was connected')
    while 1:
        recieve_message = client_socket.recv(1024)
        client_socket.send(recieve_message.upper())

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
print('server starts')
server_socket.listen(1)
while 1:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    Thread(target=handler, args=(client_socket, client_address)).start()
#-----------------------------------------
#Клиент
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
while 1:
    message = input()
    client_socket.send(message.encode())
    recieve_message = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(recieve_message.decode())
```

Вопрос вызывает метод listen. В качестве параметра он принимает максимальное число соединений. В данном случает он равняется 1. Но запустив сервер и пять клиентов, все они благополучно работают, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не совсем правильно понимаете этот параметр у listen. Как происходит работа серверного сокета:

- клиент подключается к серверу.
- его ставят в очередь (и этот параметр у listen определяет размер очереди)
- если в очереди уже нет места - клиенту отказывают в подключении.
- отдельно сам сервер вызывает accept  для сокета. Этим он забирает одного клиента с очереди сокетов, ожидающих подключение.

Теперь законный вопрос, а сколько же ставить размер очереди? Она должна  быть такой, что бы код успевал принять всех клиентов. То есть, если Вы тестируете и подкючаетесь одним клиентом и следующее подключение будет только после обрабоки  предыдущего, то даже размер в 1 будет достаточный. Если же у Вас тяжело нагруженный сервер и клиенты туда валят сотнями, а в коде могут быть затыки по accept'у клиентов, то нужно ставить побольше, я видел и 100, и 150. Но если клиенты валят с такой скоростью, что код не успевает их выгребать, то тут никакой размер очереди не поможет.

Comment: на Linux, даже если очередь готовых tcp сокетов полна (с размером, определяемым backlog), новые соединения могут приниматься пока очередь для неполных (`SYN RECEIVED`) соединений (с размером `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog`, если syncookies не включено) не заполнится.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации для [`socket.listen([backlog])`](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen):

> Enable a server to accept connections. If backlog is specified, it
>   must be at least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); **it specifies the
>   number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before
>   refusing new connections.** If not specified, a default reasonable value
>   is chosen.<sub>(выделение моё)</sub>

Выделенная часть говорит, что `backlog` параметр определяет число непринятых соединений, после которых новые соединения отвергаются. Что такое непринятое соединение и/или кол-во очередей связанных с новыми соединениями может зависеть от системы, например, см. [man listen(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) и если хочется подробностей: [How TCP backlog works in Linux](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html).

"Непринятое" соединение—это вероятно соединение, для которого `socket.accept()` метод не был вызван. Поэтому даже с `server_socket.listen(1)` ваш сервер может сколько угодно (пока кол-во запущенных потоков систему не подвесит) одновременных клиентов обслуживать, если между *открытиями* новых соединений достаточна пауза, чтобы новый поток запустился и следующий `server_socket.accept()` мог бы вернуться.